# Stop mp3 fille which is in loop

Tags: python, pygame

I want to stop the mp3 file immediately at key stroke by user. Here is my code:

```
From pygame import mixer
Import time

def music(file) :
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(file)
    while True :
        try :
           mixer.music.play() # duration of file 2 sec
           time.sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt :
           mixer.music.stop()
           break
```

Now it works, it stop the loop but after complete the playing the whole mp3. I want it to stop immediately just like an alarm. Although same file in `py.exe` stop the loop immediately. But not in IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the music immediately, you can set up a key listener with a callback to stop the mixer.

This code worked in IDLE:

```
from pygame import mixer
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def stopsound(evt):
    global running
    mixer.music.stop()  # stop music
    running = False  # exit run loop
    return False  # stop key listener

def music(file) :
    global running
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(file)
    running = True;
    while running :
        try :
           mixer.music.play() # duration of file 2 sec
           time.sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt :
           mixer.music.stop()
           break
           
with Listener(on_press=stopsound) as listener:
    music('SomeMusic.mp3')
    listener.join()  # wait for listener thread to finish
```